# React Native - Webview call React Native function

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is that possible create a function inside the [WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) component, trigger React Native function?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? React native is powerful which is using native android or ios API to  give strength to application build with React native. There might be some other good way to achieve without using WebView.

Comment: Can u be more specific about your requirements

Answer (score 7):

It's possible but I'm not sure if it's the only way to do this.

Basically you can set an `onNavigationStateChange` event handler, and embed function call information in navigation url, here's an example of the concept.

In React Native context

```
render() {

    return <WebView onNavigationStateChange={this._onURLChanged.bind(this)} />
}

_onURLChanged(e) {

    // allow normal the natvigation
    if(!e.url.startsWith('native://'))
        return true
    var payload = JSON.parse(e.url.replace('native://', ''))
    switch(e.functionName) {
        case 'toast' :
            native_toast(e.data)
        break
        case 'camera' :
            native_take_picture(e.data)
        break
    }
    // return false to prevent webview navitate to the location of e.url
    return false

}
```

To invoke native method, use this just trigger webview's navigation event and embed the function call information in URL.

```
window.location = 'native://' + JSON.stringify({ 
    functionName : 'toast', data : 'show toast text' 
})
```

Comment: Is it just me or does this throw `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` on android?

Answer (score 5):

use [`onMessage`](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onmessage) eventListner on `<WebView/>`

```js
<WebView onMessage={onMessage} ... />
```

```js
/** on message from webView -- window.ReactNativeWebView?.postMessage(data) */
  const onMessage = event => {
    const {
      nativeEvent: {data},
    } = event;

    if (data === 'goBack') {
      navigation.goBack();
    } else if (data?.startsWith('navigate')) {
      // navigate:::routeName:::stringifiedParams
      try {
        const [, routeName, params] = data.split(':::');
        params = params ? JSON.parse(params) : {};
        navigation.navigate(routeName, params);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  };
```

use this in your HTML to post message event

```js
window.ReactNativeWebView?.postMessage("data")
```

Comment: import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview'

Answer (score 2):

You could inject a javascript function to the webview on load and then use onMessage to get response from the function you injected more info [IN Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160221/react-native-webview-postmessage-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible , it existe a package for that [react-native-webview-bridge](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge).
I used it heavily in production and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi Sidali Hallak, which react native version u using? Because i'm using 0.30 and install it. It's cause this issue https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge/issues/137

Comment: i was using 0.25  , i finished the project two months ago

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure, but my opinion is -

You can not. Webview can load only js part which we can define in Webview component. This is totally separate than other components, it is only just a viewable area.